# Generating large sparse images in Julia

Tags: julia

Is it possible to generate a large sparse image in Julia?
The (excellent) library `Images.jl` by Tim Holy looks like it is meant for full image matrices where one defines every pixel.

[image]

I would like to make a [bifurcation diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bifurcation_diagram), which is rather sparse. Ideally I'd like to make one that is poster-size, but the corresponding full image matrix would be way too large to generate.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I don't think Images.jl is the right approach here. Wouldn't you be better off using a graphing library like Gadfly (https://github.com/dcjones/Gadfly.jl)? How did you create the png that you included above?

Comment: Oh - what I have above is just a link to the wikipedia entry. I would like to be able to make a large, high-res image, but I was hoping there was a way to directly write to a compressed image format rather than having to create a huge matrix.     Using a plotting library to handle it may be a good solution.

Comment: To be clear - I want to make a poster that I can give to a friend. It could be that generating a PDF with a plotting library is the way to go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An `Image` can be created from any `AbstractArray`, which includes a sparse matrix:

```
julia> using Images

julia> S = sprand(10^4, 10^4, 0.01);

julia> img = grayim(S)
Gray Images.Image with:
  data: 10000x10000 Base.SparseMatrix.SparseMatrixCSC{Float64,Int64}
  properties:
    colorspace: Gray
    spatialorder:  x y
```

Now, what you *do* with this image will determine how happy you'll be with this. But nothing prevents you from defining it.

UPDATE: Images now treats any `AbstractArray` as an image, there is no `Images` type anymore.

Comment: constructing the image works but I cannot save it: `imwrite(img, "test.png")` throws a conversion error. Pdf and jpg also throw errors.